# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when redirecting http to https using nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, https, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to redirect http requests to https using nodejs.
Here is my code so far. I have included all key, certs etc.
http and https ports are ON ( custom ports, not defaults)

Now on hitting http, site does get redirected to https but it shows err as shown in screenshot attached. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka92d.png).

certs are valid ( see bottom of screenshot ) but still it says THIS PAGE IS NOT SECURE.

Please guide me where i'm wrong and possible solution.

I have searched here but couldn't get solution to this. Thanks.

```
   var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var http_port    =any_port; 
var app = require('express')();

// HTTPS definitions
var https = require('https');
var https_port    =another_port; 
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('example.key'),
    cert:fs.readFileSync('example.crt'),
    ca:  fs.readFileSync('bundleexample.crt')
};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.end('Hello https World!');
});

https.createServer(options, app).listen(https_port, function () {
   console.log('https port ' + https_port); 
});

// Redirect from http port to https

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'].replace(http_port,https_port) + req.url });
    res.end();
}).listen(http_port);
```